# Android ListView with detail page null object

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating a listview from the contents of my api, if I click on a listview item I want to show a new view with more details for that clicked item, currently the listview gets shown properly but if I click on an item the app crashed and I get this error message:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{de.dev.app/de.dev.app.ui.quote.ArticleDetailActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String de.dev.app.jokeapp.entities.Joke.getTitle()' on a null
> object reference  ...  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> de.dev.app.entities.Joke.getTitle()' on a null object reference
>                                                                       at
> de.dev.app.ui.quote.ArticleDetailFragment.onCreateView(ArticleDetailFragment.java:100)
```

The error points to this lines in my ArticleDetailFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflateAndBind(inflater, container, R.layout.fragment_article_detail);
    if (!((BaseActivity) getActivity()).providesActivityToolbar()) {
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setToolbar((Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(jokeItem.getTitle()); // points here
    author.setText(jokeItem.getTitle());
    quote.setText(jokeItem.getTitle());
    jokeHeader.setText(jokeItem.getTitle());
    jokeContent.setText(jokeItem.getContent());

    return rootView;
}
```

This is my onAttach method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle == null) {
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }
    jokeItem = (Joke)bundle.getSerializable("joke");
}
```

This is my ArticleDetailFragment looks like:

```
public class ArticleDetailFragment extends BaseFragment {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // load dummy item by using the passed item ID.
            dummyItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(preferences);
        service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManager);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflateAndBind(inflater, container, R.layout.fragment_article_detail);
        if (!((BaseActivity) getActivity()).providesActivityToolbar()) {
            // No Toolbar present. Set include_toolbar:
            ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setToolbar((Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        }
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(jokeItem.getTitle());
        author.setText(jokeItem.getTitle());

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // your logic
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle == null) {
            getActivity().finish();
            return;
        }
        jokeItem = (Joke)bundle.getSerializable("joke");
    }

}
```

My ArticleDetailActivity

```
public class ArticleDetailActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        ArticleDetailFragment fragment =  ArticleDetailFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getStringExtra(ArticleDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.article_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean providesActivityToolbar() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling the ArticleDetailActivity in my ListActivit like this:

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity implements ArticleListFragment.Callback {
...
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Joke joke) {

            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ArticleDetailActivity.class);
            // detailIntent.putExtra(ArticleDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Add your code which you are creating this fragment.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendranhi again my friend it is the same issue we talked about last week remember, updated code aswell

Comment: Could you add the code in your Activity which call ArticleDetailFragment

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran added see updated question

Comment: You didn't sent the **Joke** object, so its crashing, Sorry could you add the code which calls this ArticleDetailActivity.java

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call DetailActivity like this from your ListActvity,

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ArticleDetailActivity.class);
// detailIntent.putExtra(ArticleDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("joke", joke);
detailIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

and change your ArticleDetailActivity change like this, we need to send data to fragment

```
public class ArticleDetailActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        ArticleDetailFragment fragment =  new ArticleDetailFragment();

        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.article_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean providesActivityToolbar() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Roemove **if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // load dummy item by using the passed item ID.
            dummyItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }** in your ArticleDetailFragment

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code to your `ArticleDetailFragment` class

```
@BindView(R.id.title)
TextView title;
```